# Twitter Bootstrap search box in navbar renders differently in chrome and firefox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following navbar on my website - the idea is that the logo, the links and a search box with a button should all be displayed in one line, as it is currently rendered in Chrome:

[image: chrome]

However. when I open the website in Firefox, it is displayed like that:

[image: firefox]

Here's the code:

```
<header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation" id="navbarStyle">             
          <div class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">      
            <a href="<?=base_url()?>">Brand</a>
           </div> 

       <div class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">                         
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left navbar-search" role="search">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="col-lg-1">    
                            <input type="text" class="form-control"placeholder="Search">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                            </button>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>

            <div>
                <ul class="nav nav-justified">
                    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

I've been struggling to fix this issue for good few hours now, but without any success. Any help will be much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason I believe you are having a problem is your use of the `col-lg-1` class on the div surrounding the form control. This was forcing the width of that did to be 1/12th the width of the parent element (which is already pretty small). This then forced the search button onto the next line. You could get rid of this surrounding div completely and it would just make itself the max width of the parent. Have another look through the docs for the bootstrap Grid and make sure you know exactly how you should be using it.

You should also wrap your search button in `<span class="input-group-btn">..your button..</span>` to make it render properly - See http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons

Here's my adjusted version of your code

```
<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation" id="navbarStyle">             
        <div class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">      
            <a href="<?=base_url()?>">Brand</a>
        </div> 

        <div class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">                         
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-left navbar-search" role="search">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                            </button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

        <div>
            <ul class="nav nav-justified">
                <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Note that I haven't tested this much at all, and I don't think it renders well on small screens, but I don't think it did that too well anyway. But give it a go and hope it helps.